# Debug node modules in VS Code on webpack-dev-server npm script process

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a node module which is throwing an error when I run `npm start` or `npm run-script debug`.

These are the scripts I have in **package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 9229 --env.mode development",
    "debug": "webpack-dev-server --port 9229 --env.mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

and in VS Code's **launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch via NPM",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script", "debug"
            ],
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

when I start debugging it does not break on any of the breakpoints I set in *webpack.config.js* or in the *node_modules* but it outputs the errors I'm getting in the VS Code's debug console.